# How to set alternate row background color using javascript

Tags: javascript, background-color, alternate

I am new to ASP.Net. I want to set the HTML table alternate row background color using javascript.
How can I start with it.If I do like this,

```
<tr  id="230552" onClick="HighLightTR(230552);"><td>My Text Here</td></tr>  


   function HighLightTR (grpid) {  
   document.getElementById(grpid).style.background = '#3875D7';         
}
```

it will apply only for that perticuler row. I want to apply two colors for alternate rows.

Comment: Do you want to change the color only when you click on it ?

Comment: are u generating tr dynamically?

Comment: you can do it using CSS effortlessly.

Comment: I am creating HTNL table in source code. I want to set color on page load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it this way

```
var rowCount=0;
$('#tbl tr').each(function () {  

 if(rowCount%2==0){
  //document.getElementById(grpid).style.background = '#3875D7';  
  $(this).css(background,'#3875D7');       
 }else
 {
 //document.getElementById(grpid).style.background = '#3875D9';  
 $(this).css(background,'#3875D9');              
 }
 rowCount++;

});
```

**EDITED:**
Code has been converted to pure jQuery standard

happy Coding :)

Comment: http://www.dotnetlearners.com/javascript/set%20table%20alternative%20row%20background%20colour%20using%20javascript.aspx          in Javascript

Comment: What if I want to have a column a red, two columns blue, a column red, two columns blue, and so on? Can you help me with this, please?

Comment: That's easy apply the background color to `td` instead of `tr`. Since you need to add different colours to different color, use class selector and write a CSS class for applying respective color. You don't need jquery for that